# How do you mark class with TypeConverter that is not in referenced solution?

Tags: .net, typeconverter

I have a class that I've written a TypeConverter for. I want to keep the TypeConverter separate from the main solution, as it is only needed at design time and have an extensibility project now that contains the TypeConverter. Thus, when I deploy, I don't need to deploy the extensibility assembly at all.

However, I can't figure out the appropriate string to use in the attribute to actually connect the class to the converter. Note I can't use this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyConverter)]
```

because MyConverter is in a project that isn't referenced.  I need to use the string overload, but can't figure out what to use:

```
[TypeConverter("what the heck goes in here!")]
```

I think I need maybe a path to the assembly, maybe a GUID, the class name...just not sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[TypeConverter("TypeName, AssemblyFullName")]
```

Comment: Kind of hoping for some help with the "AssemblyFullName" part. :-/

Comment: If you know what type it is, check the `AssemblyQualifiedName` of the type converter you're trying to use.

Comment: Between Paulo and SLaks, I got it figured out! Thanks!